# How to sum rows of two or more csv files that have the same value in column 1?

Tags: python

I have two csv files which look like this:

csv1.csv:

```
   COL1      COL2
   Daniel    120
   Max       340 
   Sabrina   5
```

csv2.csv:

```
   COL1      COL2
   Max       120
   Sabrina   40
   Daniel    50
   Sarah     580
```

And I basically want to merge them so it looks like this:

```
   COL1      COL2
   Sarah     580
   Max       460
   Daniel    170
   Sabrina   45
```

It it possible to achieve this in python?

I only found similar questions regarding 1 csv file, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be easily done using [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org). Do you want that, or you want this to be done in pure Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `merge`.
`df1` is the DataFrame from `csv1` and `df2` is the DataFrame from `csv2`

```py
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas

# setting up the dataframe from you example
d1 = [['Daniel'  ,  120],
['Max'     ,  340], 
['Sabrina' ,  5]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

d2 = [['Max'     ,  120],
['Sabrina' ,  40],
['Daniel'  ,  50],
['Sarah'   ,  580]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns=['col1', 'col2'])


# here comes the part to calculate 
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on='col1', how='outer').fillna(0)
df_out['col2'] = df_out['col2_x'] + df_out['col2_y']

# remove the unnecesary columns
df_out.drop(columns=['col2_x', 'col2_y'], inplace=True)

print(df_out)
```

```
      col1  col2
0   Daniel   170
1      Max   460
2  Sabrina    45
3    Sarah   580
```

Comment: If you are providing a solution using `pandas`, you might as well let OP know a bit about it as well. Also, include steps to install and create a `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Add values in a dictionary, something like this:

```
with open('csv1.csv') as f,open('csv2.csv') as f2:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    dict3 = {x[0]: x[1] for x in r}
    r2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=' ')
    for row in r2:
        if 'COL' not in row[1]:
            dict3[row[0]] = int(dict3[row[0]]) + int(row[1])
print(dict3)
```

now you just write dict3 in an output file.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f3:
    please = csv.writer(f3)
    for k, v in dict3.items():
       please.writerow([k + ' ' +str(v)])
```